# Bash script to check for password criteria with password encryption

Tags: bash, encryption, passwords, logic

> My code fails to validate some of the logical criteria giving in the if statement. I'm new to bash so any help would be great. My code runs, but fail in my logic. Also, I would like to learn more advance ways to write bash script. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
function validatePassword ()
        {           
                local stat=1    #assigns 1 to (stat)
                local pass=$1
                LEN=${#pass}    #counts each character in the password length
                echo $LEN       #Prints string length
                        #checks for nums        chesks for lowercase    checks for uppercase            checks if pass is greater than 8
                if  [[ $pass =~ [0-9] ]] && [[ $pass =~ [a-z] ]] && [[ $pass =~ [A-Z] ]]  && [[ "$LEN" -ge 8 ]]; then 
                        stat=$?         #return 1 for false
                fi  
                return $stat
        }   
function encryptPassword ()
        {
                dual=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
                phrase=$encryptedPassword
                rotat=13
                newphrase=$(echo $phrase | tr "${dual:0:26}" "${dual:${rotat}:26}")
                echo "Your encrypted password is ${newphrase}"
        }   

#Promts the user for input storing into variable PASSWORD
read -p "Enter your password:" -e PASSWORD

passwordToCheck=$PASSWORD 
encryptedPassword=$PASSWORD

validatePassword $passwordToCheck       #Calls function passsing value of (PASSWORD)
encryptPassword $encryptedPassword      #Calls function passing value of (PASSWORD)

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then         #(-ne) not equal command  
        echo "Invalid password"
else
        echo "Password is valid"
fi



#! /bin/bash
```

read -p "Enter a numbers:" -e input     #Prompt & read string.
echo  "Your input is $input"
echo            # passwd >= 8   #check uppder   #check lower    #check for num
if echo "$input" | egrep "^.{8,255}" | egrep "[A-Z]"| egrep "[a-z]" | egrep "[0-9]"; then
    echo "Password is valid"
else
    echo "Password is invalid"
fi

echo "$input" | tr 'A-Za-z0-5' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m6-9-5'

exit 0

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Don't you mean to place the return-value check after the validation function is called (i.e. *between* `validatePassword` and `encryptPassword`)?

Comment: I was able to get it working here is my update.       #! /bin/bash

read -p "Enter a numbers:" -e input     #Prompt & read string.
echo  "Your input is $input"
echo   # passwd >= 8  #check uppder #check lower #check for num
if echo "$input" | egrep "^.{8,255}" | egrep "[A-Z]"| egrep "[a-z]" | egrep "[0-9]"; then
 echo "Password is valid"
else
 echo "Password is invalid"
fi

echo "$input" | tr 'A-Za-z0-5' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m6-9-5'


exit 0

Answer (score 1):

The only *specified criteria* to determine whether the password is valid or not exists in `validatePassword`.  You don't check the return code after the mentioned function.  You instead check it after `encryptPassword`.

Since `encryptPassword` returns with an exit code of `0`, the `return` in the former function is ignored.

You might want to change the last few lines of your code to:

```
validatePassword $passwordToCheck       #Calls function passsing value of (PASSWORD)

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then         #(-ne) not equal command  
        echo "Invalid password"
else
        echo "Password is valid"
        encryptPassword $encryptedPassword      #Calls function passing value of (PASSWORD)
fi
```